# How to plot a table using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe from pandas.
I want to create a matplotlib table, something similar to this:

```
Zip Codes 2016  2017  2018  2019
2443       92.8  93.4 93.07 93.76
2445       94.9  94.4 95    95.13
```

This is the dataframe i have:

```
 Zip Codes,Year,Growth
        2443,2016,92.8695652173913
        2443,2017,93.3644859813084
        2443,2018,93.07
        2443,2019,93.76
        2445,2016,94.84883720930233
        2445,2017,94.43085106382979
        2445,2018,94.99236641221374
        2445,2019,95.13725490196079
        2447,2016,94.85365853658537
        2447,2017,94.4171270718232
        2447,2018,93.65760869565217
        2447,2019,94.12021857923497
```

How can i pivot the data and display it as above?

Comment: Although matplotlib has a [table function](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html), it is designed to plot a table, not to generate it. A pandas print out is probably more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas pivot method. Something like:

`df.pivot(index="Zip Codes", columns="Year", values="Growth")`